# Use PHP functions in PHP extension

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

Can I use a PHP function such as `explode()` when creating an extension in C++?

Comment: C++ will explode all by itself, it doesn't need any help from PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here it is](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/string.c#1013): `PHP_FUNCTION(explode)` expands to `zif_explode` with [these parameters](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend.h#INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS). That's the function you should call.

[Read this](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.565.1.38/1/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

PHP functions are usually implemented as parameter type checks followed by calling a native function, usually with the same name prefixed by `php_`.

For example, `explode` calls either `php_explode` or `php_explode_negative_limit` depending on the value of the third parameter ([look at the source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/string.c?revision=306938&view=markup#l1040)).

You can get the prototypes for these by including `<ext/standard/php_standard.h>`.

Make sure to check the implementation of the original PHP function for the preconditions on the arguments.